# Error with web.config and report viewer in Asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=MSKUWWEBDB; Database=SchoolVisit; User Id=msrtest; password=qazcxzedc; Connection Timeout=1200; Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>       
    <add key="RequestEmail" value="WYousef@baroue.com;PBhattacharyya@ms-retail.com;barouekuwait@ms-retail.com" />
  </appSettings>
  
 <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
       <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
    </httpHandlers>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <membership>
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="false">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Login.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
 </system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am getting below error even after adding it in my HTTP handlers section in my webconfig file. I have other web applications running perfectly with the same code.Only one of the application is throwing error.

Error- Report Viewer Configuration Error
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Comment: Can you share your configs (sanitised)?

Comment: <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

Comment: Attached is My Webconfig

Comment: Hi, Any help anyone?